# how to align an element but keep the space it left reserved

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align an element but keep the space it left reserved.

Here are some images to help illustrate:

### Correct alignment

[image]

### Wrong alignment

[image]

### Demo

```css
@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
 body {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.all {
  width: 100%;
}
.chat_element_parent {
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: thick;
  height: 100px;
}
.chat_element_child {}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="left:0px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:c3c4d4;border-style:solid;border-botom:thick dotted #ff0000;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-right:none;">
      <text style="color:white;text-align:center;font-size:30px;margin:0 auto;display:block;">
        Chatter
      </text>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="left:0px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:gray;">
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' style="background-color:orange;border-color:orange;">Register</button>
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' style="width:200px;margin:-4px;">Start New Chat !</button>
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-error btn-lg' style="position:absolute;right:5;">Group chat</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:red;padding:0px;">
      <div class="chat_element_parent">
        <div class="chat_element_child">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8" style="background-color:white;height:500px;position:relative;padding:5px;">
      <div style="overflow-y:scroll;height:400px;border:solid 2px;border-color:gray;">
        <div class='all'>
          <div class='row' id="messages_area" style="background-color:#38C5E3;width:400px;float:left;border-radius:8px;padding:17px;color:white;font-size:20px;margin-left:2px;">hi , how are you doing ? yeah , so am I</div>
        </div>
        <div class='all'>
          <div class='row' id="messages_area" style="background-color:gray;float:right;right:15;width:400px;border-radius:8px;padding:17px;color:white;margin:1px;font-size:20px;">great, you ?</div>
        </div>
        <div class='all'>
          <div class='row' id="messages_area" style="background-color:#38C5E3;float:left;width:400px;border-radius:8px;padding:17px;color:white;margin-left:2px;font-size:20px;">yeah , me too.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row' style="position:fixed;bottom:0;">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;padding:0px;font-size:20px;width:200px;"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Mr self-confident Moderator , who gave you the permission to put my code in my question ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Mike s, if you read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) you will see that it is good practice to include relative code that helps other community members solve your problem. As you had to show your code to the person who provided your accepted solution, it is clear that your code is very relative to this problem. Stack Overflow is here to also help future visitors and therefore all relative information should be included in your question so no knowledge or understanding is lost

Comment: @MyHeadHurts , neither your privacy policy nor terms of use mention that

Comment: Just to clarify - I am not an affiliate of Stack Overflow, just a community member like yourself. I am not sure I understand - what doesn't the privacy policy / terms of use mention? I feel you are getting upset over something here, but it is not clear to me what it is.

Comment: @Mikes [you probably missed the part where it says](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing): _Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. **If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you**._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like so :

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1yt2fu9v/)**

```
<div class="all"><div class="black"></div></div>

<div class="all"><div class="red"></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.black {
    background-color: black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    float: right;
}

.all {
    width: 100%;
}
```

this is one between too many other solutions

**edit** : after looking at your code i find some mistakes , when declaring a class you need to use double cotes instead of single cote like so `class="clasName"`
and i have just added `height: 62px ;` to the class `all` and this is solved the issue

edited **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4345/)**

Comment: nope  its not working , please note that my code is inside a <div class='col-xs-8'> (bootstrap column)

Comment: can you post your code please ? or put it on a jsfiddle !

Answer (score 0):

You should use clearance i.e. `clear: both;`. Clear both cancels out any floats that occur before the cleared element.

Saying that the markup and the CSS you are using is very complicated and could be simplified greatly as per the following example.

```css
.message {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 17px;
  color: white;
  margin: 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #38C5E3;
  clear: both;
}
.message.to {
  background-color: gray;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class='message from'>hi , how are you doing ? yeah , so am I</div>
  <div class='message to'>great, you ?</div>
  <div class='message from'>yeah , me too.</div>

</div>
```

## Things to Note:

Don't duplicate ID's, they are designed to be used uniquely. You are currently duplicating `messages_area`.

Try to avoid using inline styles even if you are just starting out. Set yourself up with a style block in the head or an external stylesheet would be best.

When asking a question in the future, just include the minimum amount of markup that is required to replicate the problem, this will ensure people can easily identify the problem rather than sifting through lines of code that are irrelevant. Also check your code before posting, the example you have posted has incorrectly nested markup.